# как проверить авторизован ли клиент

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, mvc

Здравствуйте. Пишу программу при помощи mvc asp.net. Сейчас разрабатываю систему авторизации и столкнулся с таким вопросом: можно ли при помощи html и js (jquery) проверить, авторизован ли клиент или нет? Единственное что мне приходит в голову, это записать true или false в ViewBag и записать его в каком-либо input теге скрытом, а потом считать значение его. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что это какой-то костыль.

Comment: а Вы не хотели проверять авторизацию через сессии? https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httpcontext.session(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Смотря какая система авторизации используется. Можно, например, через куки